# Method stream() not working properly laravel dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am working with [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). When I do `stream()` method, the browser is downloading the pdf instead of displaying it. I have already tried on 3 different browsers (Mozilla, Chrome, and Edge) and I still got this problem.

This is the code:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.cetak',compact('data'));

return $pdf->setPaper('a4')->stream();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a long-standing bug with `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`.
See [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/7)

Comment: It's work for me, i have tried it.
```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', $data);
return $pdf->stream('download.pdf');
```